# Ubuntu Server on HP ML10 v2: keyboard doesn't work in installation

Tags: server, keyboard, hp

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 15.10 on my Hp ML10 v2 (with Pentium G3240).
I know about the controller raid driver problem, so I set in the bios the controller to AHCI SATA mode.
I create an USB with unetbootin and boot the ISO from it, but when the installation starts, on the first screen (language selection) the keyborad doesn't work anymore.
I use a wireless keyboard from Logitech, and tried to plug the USB reciever in the USB2 and USB3 port, but nothing changes.
I've got also an old PS/2 keyboard, but the server doesn't have the PS/2 port!
What can I do?

UPDATE
The problem was the wireless keyboard!
With a simple USB keyboard all works fine.
But now I can't boot from the Ubuntu HDD...

Comment: Having the same problem, I called HP support, they said it's not supported. Have you been able to get this to boot? I don't want to have to return this server it because I cannot use Ubuntu. Basically did everything you did aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was able to get this to work, using Ubuntu 16.04 Server LTS.  I put the detailed instructions that worked for me here:  [How can I install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server on an HP ProLiant ML10 v2 Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772848/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server-on-an-hp-proliant-ml10-v2-server)